# Binding a collection to comboboxes within a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, combobox

Ok so, I have a listview with several rows which is defined by setting the itemsource in the code. Within each row that's generated I have a combobox. In the code I have another array of objects which is the collection that this combobox should display.

I basically want it so that for each row you can select an option from the list. The list of possibilities will always be the same, hence the array.

A little bit of code to help. This is what I have for XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="lvVanList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}">Van</GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rooms">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ComboBox Name="cbSchemeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_RoomList}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Room}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
    private RoomList _RoomList;

    public populateList()
    {
        this.lvVanList.ItemsSource = this.getVans;
        this._RoomList = this.getRooms;
    }

    private class Room
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Windows { get; set; } 
    }
```

Unfortunately this shows a blank list when the combobox is open.

I do have a way around this by storing the possibilities list in the object which is binded to each row but I'm sure I should be able to just use a single collection.

It's tough to describe so if there's any information I've missed or it's not understandable please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't `_RoomList` be `public` for the Binding to work?

Comment: what is your RoomList? Is it an `ObservableCollection<>`?

Comment: They are both within the MainWindow class it should be visible even when private, right

Comment: _RoomList is just a List<Room>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the binding path (`_RoomList`) is relative to the `DataContext` of each entry of the ListView. And that `DataContext` is the displayed item and not your view.

You can solve this in multiple ways:

1. Put the list in the displayed items - that's what you already discovered and want to avoid
2. Give your view a name and use that name the binding as `ElementName`
3. In the binding, find the ancestor of the item that is the view

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `DataContext` of each row of the `ListView` is going to be the item that that row of the `ListView` is bound to. So, when binding to the `_RoomList` property, it is trying to bind to that on each item.

Instead, you need to point the `_RoomList` binding to the element containing that property. For example, if it's in the `MainWindow`, you would add the attribute `x:Name="This"` to `MainWindow`, then change your binding to be `ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=This, Path=_RoomList}`.

An example of how you could approach it would be (using a modified version of your code):

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxListViewBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="This"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvVanList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}">Van</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Rooms">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ComboBox Name="cbSchemeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoomList}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Room}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <TextBlock Text="Testing" />
            <TextBlock Text="Testing" />
            <TextBlock Text="Testing" />
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ComboBox Name="cbSchemeList"  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel}},
    Path=RoomList }" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Room}" />
```

Here `ViewModel` is what contains your `RoomList` property